# Windows hardening

Tags: windows, hardening

Can anyone point me at some good resources on Windows hardening servers and desktop? From 2000 upwards. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My go-to site for this sort of thing is the NSA.

Check out http://www.nsa.gov/ia/guidance/security_configuration_guides/operating_systems.shtml for a number of OSes that they support for hardening.

Answer (score 1):

http://nvd.nist.gov/fdcc/index.cfm

also search on disa stig!

Comment: I wish I had the balls to implement the FDCC where I work, but whiny users would roam the halls looking for my head.

Answer (score 0):

This site helped me a lot on the "acient" side :)

http://www.gotroot.com/Windows+Hardening+Guide

Answer (score 0):

The CERT(R) Guide to System and Network Security Practices by Julia Allen merits a look.

Answer (score 0):

- [CIS Security Benchmarks](http://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/browse/index.cfm?category=benchmarks.os.windows), a 300 page document, contains well-described guidelines sanctioned by Microsoft, NIST and NSA, provided for Windows Server 2000, 2003, 2008, 2012.

> The configuration recommendations contained in this document reflect
>   consensus between Microsoft Corporation, The National Institute of
>   Standards and Technology (NIST), and the Center for Internet Security
>   (CIS).
>
> At the request of Microsoft and the Center for Internet
>   Security, the National Security Agency Information Assurance
>   Directorate participated in the review of these recommendations and
>   provided comments that were incorporated into the final published
>   version.

- As mentioned before, there are the [STIGs](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/os/index.html), configuration standards for the DoD. For Windows Server 2012 there are more than 400 guidelines in xml format requiring the [STIG-viewer](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/stig_viewing_guidance.html) (jar file).